# Confusion with operators

Tags: c++

```
int i=c++ + c++;
```

Where c is also a integer and has a value of `5`. 
I thought the answer for this one is `12` or `11`! But as it turns out it is `10`. 
Can anyone explain? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: So many duplicates present. Go to the right corner of this site and check the `Related ` part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: @ooga `Where c is also a integer and has a value of 5` i think he did

Comment: Try to use search feature as much you can before posting any question. Most of the question are all ready asked by someone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be undefined behavior. See this post for further information:
[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)